# Number format in SAP crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a crystal report which have year as parameter. It is coming from the below stored procedure.

```
  ALTER PROC [dbo].[YearValuesGet]
AS  
BEGIN 
    SELECT
         '2015'  AS [YEAR]
    UNION 
    SELECT 
         '2014'  
    UNION 
    SELECT 
          '2013' 
END
```

and I have defined the properties of parameter as below

[image]

but when i run the report the result showing as below
[image]

how can i get the only years like

2015 
2014
2013

any help is appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: In some place in parameter declaration window (I have different layout here, can't say more precisely) you have to allow only display list of values (by default it displays values AND descriptions). Another thing - why TH you have years declared as strings in SQL?

Comment: @Arvo pointed correctly...it is appending both value and description select either one...